# Python: Selenium send_key can't type numbers like 5 or 6

Tags: python, selenium

So I see this issue on google selenium site but it has not been resolved yet.

when you element.send_key('12345')

it will return '123'. The 5 is parsed as backspace....

is there a work around for this?

Using latest selenium, chrome, chromedriver, python 2.7, ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you specify the exact URL and point to the exact text box you are trying to fill in?

Comment: it doesn't matter what url it is. can't type 5 or 6

Comment: Have you tried sending a raw string? In the raw string `r'12345'`, any other string interpretations should be ignored. It can be useful for writing the correct path names in Windows.

Comment: @scorreia yes, it literally interperets 5 and 6 as backspaces. I might give up doing this the selenium way and just use javascript....

Comment: This sounds like a bug! You should post on [the Selenium issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) (but first search it to see if this issue has already been brought up).

Comment: Could it be some javascript interfering with the input field? Autocomplete plugins, for instance, might mess with Selenium.
Have you tried using `send_keys_to_element(element, *keys_to_send)` instead?

Comment: Selenium doesn't have a `send_key`. Do you mean `send_keys`? Can you post your actual source code?

Comment: How do you know that the `5` is parsed as a backspace?

Comment: it deleted the 4, if I put the 5 before another number, the same results. I'm attempting to try an escape \5 to see if it can type the number only but I doubt it, and it might write \ literally. send_keys is correct.

Comment: I suspect this behaviour is a bug which is specific to a certain combination of webdriver, xvfb and selenium. Have you tried a newer version of ubuntu or using the firefox webdriver instead?

Comment: yes I have, using the latest versions

Comment: I guess this is an Ubuntu-specific bug. I have the same setup as you, with the exception of running windows 7, and everything works fine here.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well. It ended up being due to the VNC client (tightVNC) I had installed on my remote Ubuntu (16.04) instance.

I followed the advice here (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1037) and removed tightVNC. I installed vnc4server and that seemed to solve the unusual behavior of being unable to pass on specific numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the chromedriver, so I cannot test this, but an other way to type the number 5 is to use the following command:

```
Keys.NUMPAD5
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD5)
```

PS: Sending '5' works fine on the FirefoxDriver, as do the above commands

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("Https://www.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("12345")
```

Using latest selenium, chrome, chromedriver, python 2.7 on windows it is working fine

Comment: This works fine in ubuntu 14.10 as well. Perhaps the latest selenium and chromedriver for ubuntu 12.04 are outdated? I have not tested it with Xvfb, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug... I found a possible workaround.

Searching through [the Selenium issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/), I found [this somewhat similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6074). In its discussion, [Message #9](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6074#c9) mentions a workaround: Instead of `textBox.send_keys("R&d")`, using `textBox.send_keys("R/&d")` and later deleting the extra `/` character worked properly. The extra character was deleted like so:

```
textBox.send_keys("R/&d")
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

I can't test this since I don't have a setup similar to yours. I'd be happy to hear whether this works!

Comment: this is the best answer so far, I will post my findings.

Comment: You might get lucky, or figure out what exactly goes wrong if you send the keys individually somehow. For instance `send_keys(list('12345'))` or `for letter in '12345': element.send_keys(letter)`, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `send_keys()` method works as it should in my windows setup, but I constructed a little method that might solve your problem. It is, like other have already suggested, using the `selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys` constants:

```
def send_keys_workaround(element, string):
    for s in string:
        if s == '5':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD5)
        elif s == '6':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD6)
        else:
            element.send_keys(s)
```

I have set up a minimalistic jsfiddle, to test if it works on windows at least. I hope it will work on your Ubuntu too. The full script is here:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def send_keys_workaround(element, string):
    for s in string:
        if s == '5':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD5)
        elif s == '6':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD6)
        else:
            element.send_keys(s)


driver = WebDriver("****INSERT PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER***")
driver.get("http://jsfiddle.net/zwktb7tn/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 2) 
wait.until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'result')))

element = driver.find_element_by_id('inputfield')
send_keys_workaround(element, "123456")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to jump4fun for his workaround.  Have used it in my code and it works.  I can enter digits into the command line, they are converted to a string for the send_key.

```
if page_number == 1:
   pass
else:
   print('Attempt to start from Page', page_number)
   driver.find_element_by_id(page_number_id).click()
   driver.find_element_by_id(page_number_id).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
   driver.find_element_by_id(page_number_id).clear()
   element = driver.find_element_by_id("pageNumber")
   # send_keys doesn't like numbers directly from the gui but is OK if NUMPAD is used
   # this workaround maps the entered digits to the send_key string argument
   send_keys_workaround(element, str(page_number)) 
   driver.find_element_by_id(page_number_id).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# obtain the current page and last page numbers
page=soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'text-lg-right'})
# print(page)
page_number = page.input['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

As dear @Epiwin mentioned ,it is a horrible bug in TightVNC or combination of chrome driver and it, I've removed it completely and install TigerVNC instead and eventually it worked.
BTW, I don't know why! but the speed of the remote connection increased after migrate to TigerVNC, and it was another good point for mine.

Answer (score 0):

8 years later, the problem is still here.
The problem I have is about tightvnc server. I change it to x11vnc

```
# vncserver -kill :1
export DISPLAY=:1
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
x11vnc -create -env FD_PROG=/home/$USER/.vnc/xstartup \
-env X11VNC_FINDDISPLAY_ALWAYS_FAILS=1 \
-env X11VNC_CREATE_GEOM==${1:-1280x1024x24} \
-rfbport 5901 -bg -nopw -forever -ncache 10 &
```

You can also try any of these functions

```
def send_keys(self, element, string):
    self.driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + string + "')", element)
def send_keys_bitbybit(self, element, string):
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        char = string[i]
        # some bugs not able to send 6
        if char == '5':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD5)
        elif char == '6':
            element.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD6)
        else:
            element.send_keys(char)
        time.sleep(0.2)
def send_keys_action(self, element, string):
    ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys_to_element(element, string).perform()
```